# Print text pyramid with spacing

Tags: python, cgi, python-2.x, spacing

http://tekknolagi.co.cc/cgi-bin/helloworld.py

that's the output

what i would like it to do is make a pyramid shape

here's the code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print



for i in range(1,10):
    x = "hi "*i
    print x.rjust(40)

for i in range(1, 10):
    x = " hi"*i
    print x.ljust(40)
```

how do i get it to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print x.rjust(40) + x.ljust(40)
```

Comment: now as an extension...u have experience with pascal's triangle?

Comment: @tekknolagi, I hope this is not extending to a homework problem.

Comment: of course not. it's all experimental. that's quite an accusation. taking a C class, not a python class.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `center` command so that you can print both sides at once:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    x = " hi" * i * 2
    print x.center(80)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had no clue about these justification functions.

A little ipython auto completion showed me a `center` method.

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    x = "hi " * i
    print x.center(40)
```

Ya learn something every day.

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

for i in range(1,10):
    x = "hi "*i
    print x.rjust(40), x.ljust(40)
```

> ```
>                                   hi  hi                                
>
>                                hi hi  hi hi                             
>
>                             hi hi hi  hi hi hi                          
>
>                          hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi                       
>
>                       hi hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi hi                    
>
>                    hi hi hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi hi hi                 
>
>                 hi hi hi hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi hi hi hi              
>
>              hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi           
>
>           hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi  hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi
> ```